# Which user samba4-AD account for service on windows server

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-service

I am a linux sysadmin by trade - please forgive this 'basic' question.

In an ad-controlled environment (using samba 4), I want to setup a server with windows on it, to run two windows specific services.

Which user account should I use to install these services on the windows machine?
I thought about using my personal AD account, or the administrator AD account, or the local administrator account, but none of these seem like a good choice. What is the right way to go? From my knowledge, "Managed Service Accounts" are unfortunately not supported by samba 4.

Comment: Install it, like in copying the files, changing the registry etc., or run it, like the effective UID the service process will have?

Comment: @stickybit I'd like to know the best practice both for installation and effective service process uid. (If these can differ without having to change lots of permissions or similar)